# Action Bar not displaying Action Items (All in overflow) Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I can't get the Action Bar to display my action items.  They all show up in the overflow menu.  I have pasted all the relevant code below.  Can anyone see my problem?

From Activity:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.viewer_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menu_download:
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_star:
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_report:
        return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

From Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".CustomActivity"

     android:label="">
```

From values-v11 folder (themes.xml)

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
</style>
```

from menu folder (viewer_menu.xml)

```
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_download"
    android:title="Download" showAsAction="withText"
    android:orderInCategory="2"/>
<item android:id="@+id/menu_star"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload"
    android:title="Star"
     showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="1"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_report"
    android:title="Report Problem" showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="0"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `android:showAsAction`, not just `showAsAction`.

Comment: I have all the same code, mine still doesn't bring up the action bar... :(

Answer (score 4):

If you are using support package (`android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`), you have to use something like this:

```
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_download"
      android:title="Download" 
      app:showAsAction="withText"
      android:orderInCategory="2"/>

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_star"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload"
      android:title="Star"
      app:showAsAction="always"
      android:orderInCategory="1"/>

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_report"
      android:title="Report Problem" 
      app:showAsAction="always"
      android:orderInCategory="0"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

what version is the android emulator you are running?

Also, have you tried the http://actionbarsherlock.com/ version yet?